# Create an ENUM type from query result

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

I am getting all the built-in and user defined types in order to use the resulting list of types as possible values for a new user defined ENUM type.

```
SELECT pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid, NULL) into TYPES_NAMES
FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
WHERE (t.typrelid = 0 OR (SELECT c.relkind = 'c' FROM  
pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid))
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el WHERE el.oid =    
t.typelem AND el.typarray = t.oid)
AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid);
```

How can I use the resulting types list as possible values that the new `ENUM`type can have.

```
CREATE TYPE my_enum AS ENUM ( .... );
```

I am using `PostgreSQL 9.5.0`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the values in plpgsql and add them to your enum with:

```
ALTER TYPE name ADD VALUE 'value';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I could do it by iterating over the values.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it with an inline command by iterating over the values thx to Dmitri's answer.

```
DO $$
DECLARE name text;
BEGIN
  --  create an empty type then add the possible values
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE data_types_enum AS ENUM ()';
  FOR name IN
    SELECT pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid, NULL) as TYPES_NAMES
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
    LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
    WHERE (t.typrelid = 0 OR (SELECT c.relkind = 'c' FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid))
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el WHERE el.oid =
    t.typelem AND el.typarray = t.oid)
    AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid)
  LOOP
     -- add the possible types 
     EXECUTE 'ALTER TYPE data_types_enum ADD VALUE ''' ||name|| '''';
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```